# How is the universe expanding?

Tags: astronomy, astrophysics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [spacetime expansion and universe expansion?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24324/spacetime-expansion-and-universe-expansion)

Is the space between planets is growing or the space between stars is growing or the space between galaxies is growing?

Comment: The space between galaxies.  Only non-bound objects are expanding away from each other.  But I"m sure this question has been answered before.

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24324/spacetime-expansion-and-universe-expansion

Comment: Have a look at the middle bit of my answer to the question Jerry mentions. This addresses exactly your question. The answer is that "spacetime" is growing everywhere, but the distance between objects only increases on the scale of galaxy clusters. That's because smaller objects are held together by gravity and resist the expansion.