# Expansion of space

Tags: space-expansion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [spacetime expansion and universe expansion?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24324/spacetime-expansion-and-universe-expansion)

So I've heard that space is expanding very quickly and that the redshift we see when we look at other galaxies is evidence of this. But why doesn't this expansion affect orbits of the planets in our solar system, for instance? I would think that the expansion of space is uniform through the universe...why doesn't it tear our bodies apart?

Comment: Answered here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24324/spacetime-expansion-and-universe-expansion. Also, Woody's mom is correct here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Pa34orcwwA