# is the expansion of the universe observable at a smaller scale?

Tags: universe

I have searched the network for a possible duplicate to this question but I have not found one particulary answering my question so recommendations are welcome.

I understand that distances of celestial bodies from earth can be estimated by using knowledge of nuclear  fussion, the doppler effect and spectral colors of wavelengths visible to humans (red and blue shift).

Knowledge of the distances, speeds and frequencies of wave emmisons from distant galaxies have led to the general assumption that the universe is expanding.

What is evidence of the universe expanding on a smaller scale like solar systems and even planetary behaviour if any

Comment: There is a paper, I forgot which right now, that I read one time that calculated the corrections due to expansion on solar system scales; It amounted to something very tiny, impossible to observe.

Comment: Also related: [spacetime expansion and universe expansion?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24324/spacetime-expansion-and-universe-expansion)

Comment: @Danu do post when you recall